# django channels change time format of datetime field

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm new to django channels and I'm stuck on how to change the format of the datetime field in this particular binding class.

```py
class InfoBinding(WebsocketBinding):

    model =Info
    stream = "stream"
    fields = ["time_stamp"]
    
    @classmethod
    def group_names(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        
        return ["binding.values"]

    def has_permission(self, user, action, pk):
        # print(self.time_stamp)
        
        return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must probably modify DatetimeField in the has_permission().

Comment: has_permission is for updating models in django from input message